# How to set a Splat route as Default route Durandal 2.0

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

My default route has child views, can I set a Splat route as Default route in Durandal 2.0 if yes how I tried something like below but it fails , basically I want to implement a childrouter in my default view how can I do this..

```
define(['plugins/router'], function (router) {
return {
    router: router,
    activate: function () {
        return router.map([                
            { route: 'knockout-samples*details',    moduleId: 'ko/index',title: 'Knockout Samples',  nav: true, hash: '#knockout-samples' }
        ]).buildNavigationModel()              
          .activate();
    }
};
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then yes - you can have a splat as your default route. You would do something like this in your root shell:

```
router.map({
    moduleId: "child/shell",
    route: "*details"
});
```

And then in your child's view model:

```
var childRouter = rootRouter
    .createChildRouter()
    .makeRelative({ moduleId: "child" });

// Uses "child/defaultPage" as the view model, and "#/" as the route
childRouter.map({
    moduleId: "defaultPage",
    route: ""
});
```

Hope that helps.